Test run fail using TestNG and sure-fire plugin
@Test
    public void testSendWebhook() throws KafkaConsumerException {
        PodamFactory factory = new PodamFactoryImpl();
        WebhookEventDTO<MeetingEventPayload> webhookEventDTO = factory.manufacturePojo(WebhookEventDTO.class, MeetingEventPayload.class);
        Mockito.when(u2CBizService.getWebhookFeatureToggleEndpoint(any(), any(), eq("webhook-engine"), any())).thenReturn("https://www.ciscospark.com/v1");
        Mockito.doNothing().when(webhookFeignClient).sendWebhookEvent(any(), any(), any());
        webhookRemoteService.sendWebhook(webhookEventDTO, "trackingId");
        Mockito.verify(webhookFeignClient, Mockito.times(1)).sendWebhookEvent(any(), any(), any());
    } 

When I run this method directly in IntelliJ IDEA, it works fine. However, when I run it through Maven test, it fails, showing the following error：
[ERROR]   WebinarFeignServiceTest.testHeaderInterceptor:44 » UnfinishedStubbing 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.cisco.webex.notificationservice.remote.webhook.WebhookRemoteServiceTest.testSendWebhook(WebhookRemoteServiceTest.java:45)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3. you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction is completed

here part of pom
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                    <reportFormat>plain</reportFormat>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

I don't have any idea to this failure.

Please edit your question and share the complete sample.

Which version of surefire plugin do you use? Also the testng versions is not up-to-date... why defined includes in the surefire setup? And the error messages posted showing you are using mockito but you have mocked to many things or wrong... but without that code it's impossible to see ...

Is it caused by running in multi-threaded mode? BTW the version of surefire plugin is 3.0.0-M9，and i tried newest version of testng
